# Why is my list returning empty when reading a file?

Tags: python, list, file, if-statement

I am working on a project that reads a file in which the beginning lines in each file have a letter that represents what that line is doing. For example, if the line begins with 'p' then this line contains a coordinate.

I am trying to add all the lines that begin with p in their own list. Then make the coordinates into tuples. This is the code I am running to do so:

```
pList=[]
if [0] in makeList is 'p':
    pList=[tuple(map(int, l.split()[2:3])) for l in makeList.readlines()]
    pList.append(line.strip())
```

My problem is when I run a diagnostic print, the list is coming back empty. I am new to programming so I am having a hard time troubleshooting this one. Thank you!

Comment: Hints for troubleshooting - reduce the `if` statement to one condition and replace the conditional code with a `print("condition met")` statement to see if it is hit. If not, research why, if yes - add one more statement and see if it still hit. Iterate until fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Your compound [comparison chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) (thx @KellyBundy) is never met:

```
if [0] in makeList .... :    --> True or False 

if makeList is 'p':`  --> False
```

You use `makeList.readlines()` suggesting that `makeList` is your file-descriptor which makes your condition more nonsensical.

Normally you would do something like:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] == 'p': # or line.startswith(...) - do not compare with IS
            # split line, convert to int, make tuple, add to list
```

Comment: @Kelly thx, fixed

Comment: Might not be quite clear for someone who doesn't know it already, but I guess with the link they can figure it out. In any case, yeah, one of the two comparisons is going to be false, regardless of whatever `makeList` is.

Comment: Silly little challenge: Find out how to make `[0] in makeList and makeList is 'p'` true.